# iPhone predicate: One of each

Tags: iphone, nspredicate

I was wondering if it was possible to run a query using a predicate specifying "one of each."  They do not seem to have anything similar to this in the predicate documentation.

Appreciate any help or resources.

UPDATE: I want to return every unique instance in a column which contains duplicates.

Comment: Clarification: Do you mean it returns one object for each value, that a collection has at least one of two different criteria or something else?

Comment: I want to return every unique instance in a column which contains duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the results of your `NSPredicate` and put them into an [`NSSet`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (or its mutable child `NSMutableSet`). By definition, a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) contains no duplicates.